# Definir imagem do link com Meta-tags do Facebook Open Graph

Tags: imagem, facebook, html-meta-tag

Estou trabalhando num blog de uma minha amiga e quando eu abro uma postagem, copio o link e colo no facebook a primeira imagem que aparece é a foto dela que está numa outra `div` dentro da barra lateral no lado direito do blog e não a imagem da postagem.

Para que a imagem desejada da postagem apareça é necessário clicar nas setinhas até aparecer a imagem que eu quero. Como neste exemplo abaixo:

> Copio o link dessa postagem

[image]

> Quando colo o link no Facebook aparece a imagem que eu não quero que
>   apareça como imagem padrão (ou seja como primeira imagem), vejam
>   abaixo a imagem que fica na barra lateral direita se intrometendo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Mas quando eu pego o link de outros sites e posto no Facebook, aparece
>   logo a imagem da postagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como é que eu faço para que a imagem das postagens apareça no Facebook como no exemplo do site `MyCnb` que mostrei? É programação? me ajudem por favor

> (obs: quando ela posta o link da postagem do blog no facebook dela,
>   nenhuma imagem aparece.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para que as imagens apareçam correctamente no Facebook, é necessário o uso de [**meta tags**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp). Neste caso para o Facebook, é requerido um conjunto especial de `meta tags` como o @Maicon já mencionou, chamadas de [**Open Graph Protocol**](http://ogp.me/) ou abreviado OG Meta tags.

Para adicioná-las ao seu site Blogger, Navegue até - `Blogger > Dashboard > Template > Edit HTML`
No topo do editor, irás encontrar um código que se parece com este:

```
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'
xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b'
xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' 
xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
```

Cole o código `xmlns:og='http://ogp.me/ns#'` antes do encerramento desta tag `html`. Exemplo:

```
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'
xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b'
xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data'
xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'
xmlns:og='http://ogp.me/ns#'>
```

Feito isto, ele irá agora adicionar a tag [**`Open Graph Protocol`**](http://ogp.me/) que é o protocolo usado pelo Facebook ao seu Blogger. Depois disto ter sido feito, procure pela tag `<head>` que deve estar logo abaixo da tag acima referida, e abaixo desta tag `head` cole o código:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
    <meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName' property='og:title'/>
    <meta expr:content='data:blog.canonicalUrl' property='og:url'/>
    <meta content='article' property='og:type'/>
</b:if>
    <meta expr:content='data:blog.title' property='og:site_name'/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl'>
    <meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl' property='og:image'/>
<b:else/>
    <meta content='IMAGEM_PERSONALIZADA_HOMEPAGE' property='og:image'/>
</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription'>
    <meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' property='og:description'/>
<b:else/>
    <meta expr:content='&quot;Ler artigo sobre &quot; + data:blog.pageName + &quot; em &quot; + data:blog.title + &quot;&quot;' property='og:description'/>
</b:if>
    <meta content='ID_DA_TUA_APP_FACEBOOK' property='fb:app_id'/>
    <meta content='ADMINS_DA_TUA_APP_FACEBOOK' property='fb:admins'/>
```

Basicamente o que este `<b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription'>` vai fazer, é pegar a `meta description` caso esta exista e exibi-la como `og:description`, mas caso esta não exista e/ou não esteja disponível, então o texto `Ler artigo sobre ...` irá ser implementado como `og:description` em vez disso.

### `Meta description` no Blogger

Para activar as `meta description` você tem que ir até:

> `Definições > Preferência de pesquisa > Meta tags > Descrição` Clique em editar.
>   E irá aparecer o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Adicionar `Meta description` a publicações individuais

Simplesmente edite a sua publicação ou página e procure pela opção **Descrição da Pesquisa**, e é aqui que iremos adicionar a descrição de cada página que agora irá também ser exibida como `og:description` para o Facebook.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não te esqueças de substituir os campos:

- `IMAGEM_PERSONALIZADA_HOMEPAGE` - Imagem exibida na homepage(página inicial) e outras páginas
  Aqui deves indicar o endereço da imagem que queres que seja a imagem padrão a ser apresentada quando publicas o link da página inicial no Facebook (por exemplo - `pt.stackoverflow.com`) e esta também será a imagem padrão em outras páginas que não são publicações.
  Sim, pode ser o logo do site, mas a imagem tem que ter no mínimo `200px` de largura e altura. Deves substituir o texto `IMAGEM_PERSONALIZADA_HOMEPAGE` por algo como - `https://i.stack.imgur.com/gL1sB.jpg`
- `ID_DA_TUA_APP_FACEBOOK` - O ID da tua aplicação do Facebook
  Aqui deves colocar o ID da tua app. Esta `meta tag` e também a outra que vem a seguir `ADMINS` não são muito relevantes aqui neste caso, elas apenas são necessárias para implementação da caixa de comentários do Facebook no teu site e coisas do género, então se quiseres podes remover esta tag e a outra que vem abaixo, pois ela apenas só vai adicionar o nome da tua app/site quando alguém publica algo no Facebook, por exemplo - `O João publicou isto através da aplicação ______`. Para utilizar isto é necessário [criar uma APP no Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/developers/createapp.php). Se quiseres tens aqui um site que explica [como criar uma app](https://goldplugins.com/documentation/wp-social-pro-documentation/how-to-get-an-app-id-and-secret-key-from-facebook/) passo a passo.
  Este valor deverá ser alterado para algo como - `000111222333444555` que será o ID da app
- `ADMINS_DA_TUA_APP_FACEBOOK` - Os administradores da tua APP
  Isto também não será muito útil, pois adicionar administradores basicamente é adicionar admins para controlar a tua app. Por exemplo se estivesses a usar a caixa de comentários do Facebook no teu site, adicionando admins eles poderiam moderar os comentários no teu site e coisas do género. Mas agora também é possível adicionar admins na própria app, então se criares uma app podes apagar esta tag e adicionar os admins directamente na tua app acessando: `My Apps > Roles > Administators` na página https://developers.facebook.com após teres criado a tua app. Podes descobrir qual é o teu `user id` através do site [findMyFacebookId](http://findmyfacebookid.com/)
  Este valor deverá ser alterado para algo como - `12345678910,10987654321`

Depois de substituíres isso tudo, as meta tags deverão ficar algo como neste exemplo:

```
<meta content='https://i.stack.imgur.com/gL1sB.jpg' property='og:image'/>

<meta content='000111222333444555' property='fb:app_id'/>
<meta content='12345678910,10987654321' property='fb:admins'/>
```

Lembrando, que estas duas últimas tags não são necessariamente obrigatórias, o código irá funcionar normalmente com ou sem elas, por isso se quiser pode removê-las do código e quando precisar delas vem aqui na resposta e segue o exemplo para implementá-las no seu código.

No final disto tudo ser implementado, deverá ficar algo parecido como o código desta imagem abaixo:

[image]

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta novamente!  
<p>Me ajuda com isso aqui?<p>IMAGEM_PERSONALIZADA_HOMEPAGE - Imagem exibida na homepage(página inicial) e outras páginas
ID_DA_TUA_APP_FACEBOOK - O ID da tua aplicação do Facebook
ADMINS_DA_TUA_APP_FACEBOOK - Os administradores da tua APP

Comment: irei editar a minha resposta

Comment: Obrigado mano, fico no aguardo!!

Comment: @DiegoGomes https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

Comment: Obrigado Maicon e Chun, fiz o que vocês disseram, mas o erro persiste :/  
http://oi59.tinypic.com/157jg4i.jpg  
<p> O que pode ser agora?

Comment: @DiegoGomes a imagem não está funcionando :/ Você já experimentou usar o [Tool Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) como o Maicon lhe disse? Aparece lá algum erro? Cole o link do seu site que você deseja compartilhar nessa ferramenta Debugger do Facebook, e clique em `Fetch new scrape information` tipo umas 2 ou 3 vezes até a imagem desejada aparecer. As vezes ele não atualiza logo à primeira.

Comment: Oi Chun, depois de muita luta eu consegui  quando eu parar em casa eu explico como deu certo, muito obrigado!

Comment: De nada @DiegoGomes , ainda bem que conseguis-te resolver o problema :)

Comment: Complementando, depois da ajuda de vocês, fui atrás de mais conhecimento no próprio facebook, onde vi que tinha que adicionar um script oferecido pelo próprio facebook, não consigo colar aqui por causa do limite de caracteres, seguindo o restante que vcs me instruiram, deu certo! Muito obrigado :)

Answer (score 2):

Isso envolve o [`Open Graph`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph) do Facebook, você pode indicar pra ele qual imagem você quer exibir:

1. Primeiro adicione o namespace do `Open Graph`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

2. Depois dentro do seu `<head>` adicione um meta pra ele localizar a imagem

```
<meta property="og:image" content="url_da_imagem" />
```

Se quiser ver mais opções, por exemplo informar o título ou descrição, dê uma olhada aqui: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects

E pra forçar a atualização da sua `thumbnail` utilize o **Debugger** do FB: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Oi Maicon, obrigado pela resposta!
já adicionei os metas e o código na tag html, fui no debug mas continua do msm jeito, aparece a imagem que eu não quero como primeira ;/

Comment: @DiegoGomes Se funcionar, marque como a resposta certa :)