# Como coloco o botão "curtir" e "compartilhar" para cada post do meu blog?

Tags: html, facebook, blogger

Adicionei ao meu blog um botão **<kbd>Curtir</kbd>** e **<kbd>compartilhar</kbd>** nos rodapés dos *posts* do meu Blog, para que o leitor tenha a opção de escolher Curtir ou não, somente aquele *post*. Mas ao clicar em Curtir, observei que o botão não compartilhava o *post*, mas sim o blog.

Alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver esse problema? Gostaria de saber como colocar um botão **<kbd>Curtir</kbd>** e **<kbd>compartilhar</kbd>** que permita que o leitor curta somente aquele *post* que está lendo?

A plataforma utilizada é o Blogger. Tenho algumas páginas estáticas e para essas, sim, gostaria que aparecesse a opção de Curtir essas páginas.
Utilizei o código gerado a partir do Facebook Developers, em Social Pluggins:

```
 <!-- Insere "curtir" e "compartilhar" do facebook -->
<div id='fb-root'/>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&amp;version=v2.5";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, &#39;script&#39;, &#39;facebook-jssdk&#39;));</script>

Código HTML:
<!-- insere o botão "curtir" e o "compartilhar" do facebook -->
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://enchendoacaixa.blogspot.com.br/" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

Desde já, muito obrigada!

Comment: Isto é um blog em WordPress? Blogger? outro? Se isto é uma página estática em HTML, vocè está a criar o código dos botões `curtir`, `compartilhar` e apontando os links de partilha para cada postagem? Qual a sua estrutura do código de compartilha para as redes sociais?

Comment: Estou usando o Blogger. O código que estou utilizando é aquele disponível na página do Facebook Developers. Vou editar minha pergunta e colocar o código para vocês verem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso acontece porque estás a definir o link da página inicial do teu blog como sendo o link para ser curtido/compartilhado no código que gera esse botão:

```
data-href="http://enchendoacaixa.blogspot.com.br/"
```

Para que ele funcione como um botão de compartilhamento para cada postagem, terás que modificar este código e alterá-lo para:

```
expr:href='data:post.url'
```

que é o código de rastreamento que pega as URL's de cada publicação do Blogger dispensado pela Google para estes e outros propósitos.

No entanto para que ele funcione e pegue cada link correto de cada postagem, o código precisa de estar inserido dentro do loop de cada item/publicação, ou seja deverá estar inserido dentro da estrutura/*container* que gera cada item/publicação única dentro do teu tema. Que será dentro de um código parecido com este abaixo:

```
<b:includable id='post' var='post'>
    ....
</b:includable>
```

Após encontrares este código já sabes que estás dentro do código que gera cada item/publicação.
Dentro deste mesmo excerto de código procura o melhor lugar no qual queres implementar o código do botão **<kbd>Like</kbd>** e cola-o dentro do *post* no melhor lugar que achares que vai ficar. Tudo junto o código ficará algo como:

```
<!-- Insere "curtir" e "compartilhar" do facebook -->
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&amp;version=v2.5";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, &#39;script&#39;, &#39;facebook-jssdk&#39;));
</script>

<!-- insere o botão "curtir" e o "compartilhar" do facebook -->
<div class='fb-like' data-action='like' data-layout='button_count' data-share='true' data-show-faces='true' expr:href='data:post.url'/>
```

> Nota: Não te esqueças de sempre alterar as aspas `" "` por `' '`, eu já fiz esse alteraçáo no código que gera os botões.

Comment: Obrigada! Deu certo! Só queria saber, e não sei se preciso abrir outra pergunta aqui: Quando vou compartilhar o post aparece apenas o título, mas não imagem do post, existe alguma forma de configurar isso?

Comment: Para a imagem do post aparecer, tens que fazer upload de uma imagem para o teu blog (ou seja a imagem que queres que seja a imagem de destaque para um certo post) e adicioná-la no início da postagem utilizando o editor de HTML no post que estiveres a editar, da seguinte forma: `<img style="display:none;" src="http://i.stack.imgur.com/gL1sB.jpg" />` adiciona o `style="display:none;"` se não quiseres que esta `og:image` seja apresentada no post quando publicado, assim ela só irá servir como *data* para a `og:image`.

Comment: Podes também ver estas duas perguntas para te informar mais sobre isso: [Facebook descrição e thumbnail é pequena](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/74476/11886) e também: [Facebook Open Graph meta tags para Blogger](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/71593/11886). Se ainda tiveres dúvidas é só dizer.

Comment: Não funcionou...
Adiciono minhas imagens ao picasa web e utilizei o link, como você me sugeriu, mas não funcionou...
Uma coisa que observei é o primeiro link de imagem da página que postei e depois troquei e não atualizou até agora... quis trocar porque o tamanho fica muito maior e quase não dá ver, até editei a imagem para que tivesse um tamanho de 355x355px, e troquei o link, mas ainda não mudou... https://goo.gl/Rz8n27 Você saberia me dizer se isso demora mesmo ou tem alguma forma de arrumar isso?

Comment: Se copias-te as meta tags da pergunta do segundo link, faz [esta mudança](https://jsfiddle.net/src_code/s46pecnp/) no código das meta tags. Eu inspecionei o código fonte do teu Blog e vi que a imagem está lá, só que ele está a detetar uma imagem thumbnail demasiado pequena com o tamanho de `42px` por isso que ela ainda não mudou. Depois de atualizares debuga o link da página que atualizas-te aqui no [Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fenchendoacaixa.blogspot.com.br%2F2016%2F02%2Fpostagem-teste-3_30.html)

Comment: Mas quando inspeciono meu código aqui, a imagem aparece com 165x165

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35537/discussion-between-chun-and-vanessa-ribeiro).

Answer (score 2):

Para o botao de compartilhar,vá no Editar HTML do seu blog e procure por

```
<div class='post-header-line-1'/>
```

Embaixo disso, coloque isso:

```
<div style="float:left;padding:4px;">
<a expr:share_url='data:post.url' name='fb_share' rel='nofollow' type='button_count'/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share"/>
</div>
```

Espero que consiga. Abraços. Dúvidas? Comente na minha resposta.

Esqueci de falar.
Após feitas as alterações, vá em Design > Elementos da página

Procure o quadrado referente a "Postagens do Blog" e clique em editar.
Então, marque as caixinhas referentes ao compartilhamento e salve.